# Receive file from server using send and fwrite

Tags: c, networking, server, ipv6, ipv4

Hello I am working on a school lab in which I have to ask a server to send me a file. Here is my code so far. for some reason, when I run this code, in which I have fixed the arguments for debug purposes, it is as if I get in an infinite loop and get nothing. The problem is surely in gettftp function in the "send" function i think.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <arpa/tftp.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>




int gettftp(const char *fileName, const char *serverIp)
{
    int sock  = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(69);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serverIp);

    //sending read request
    struct tftphdr *read_request = (struct tftphdr *) malloc(sizeof(struct tftphdr) + strlen(fileName) + 1);
    read_request->th_opcode = htons(RRQ);
    strcpy(read_request->th_stuff, fileName);
    send(sock, read_request, sizeof(struct tftphdr) + strlen(fileName) + 1, 0);

    // Receive and save the file
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "wb");
    while (1) {
        char buffer[512];
        int bytes_received = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (bytes_received < 0) {
            break;
        }
        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_received, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}



/**
 * Send back the ip address of the requested server
 * @param server name inputed right after file to be executed.
 * @output none
*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   
    char* server, file;
    char buffile[100],bufsN[100];
    unsigned char ip[50] ="";
    struct addrinfo hints, *results, *rp;
    int sfd;

    argv[1] = "10.10.32.11";
    argv[2] = "alt256";




    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; /* Datagram socket */
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */

    if(argc<3)
    {
        printf("You have requested file :\033[0;31m%s\033[0m", argv[2]);    //print file name. the part that has 31 changes color to red
        printf(" from server : \033[0;31m%s\033[0m \n", argv[1]);           //print server name
    }



    int status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], "69", &hints, &results);
    if (status != 0) {
        printf("Error: getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));           //describes what the error does
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &results->ai_addr->sa_data[2], ip, sizeof(ip));  //convert ip adress which is part of a struct to string
        printf("L'adresse du serveur est: \033[0;31m%s\033[0m \n", ip);     //print server ip address
    }


    for (rp = results; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {                      //socket creation using address family (rp->ai_family), the socket type (ai_socktype)
        sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,                        //and protocol(ai_protocol)
                rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sfd == -1)                                                      //in case sfd = -1  move on to the next iteration because there is some error somewhere
            continue;


        if (connect(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1){               //if connection is successful print message and break out of the oop
            printf("Connected to server: \033[0;31m%s\033[0m \n", argv[1] );
            break;                   /* Success */
        }


        close(sfd);
    }

    if (rp == NULL) {               /* No address succeeded */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  
    //const char* filen = "alt256";
    const char* filen = argv[2];


    //const char* serverName = "srvtpinfo1.ensea.fr";
    strcpy(buffile, filen);
    strcpy(bufsN, ip);

    gettftp(buffile, bufsN);
    //gettftp("alt256", "10.10.32.11");
   
    return 0;
}
}
```

I have tries debugging to see if the parameters are right when they get in the function and that was the case

Comment: If you mean to be using the TFTP protocol, your implementation won't work.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol to start.

Comment: `argv[2] = "alt256";` is not valid if `argc <= 1` --> UB.

Comment: As code is having trouble, consider adding error checking on `fopen(), send(), inet_ntop(), fwrite(), ...`  Saves us all time and improves the quality  of the code.